# BigQuery scheduled query failing

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery scheduled query that is failing with the following error:

```
Not found: Dataset bunny25256:dataset1 was not found in location US at [5:15]; JobID: 431285762868:scheduled_query_635d3a29-0000-22f2-888e-14223bc47b46
```

I scheduled the query via the SQL Workspace. When I run the query in the workspace, it works fine. The dataset and everything else that I have created is in the same region: us-central1.

Any ideas on what the problem could be, and how I could fix it or work around it?

There's nothing special about the query, it computes some statistics on a table in `dataset1` and puts it in `dataset2`.

Comment: When you submit a query, you submit it to BQ at a given location.  The dataset you created lives in "us-central1" but your query was submitted to "us".  The location "us" and "us-central1" are not the same.  Change your scheduled query to run in "us-central1".  See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations

Comment: Thanks @Kolban! This was the issue. Recreating the scheduled query with the "data location" set to us-central1 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a query, you submit it to BQ at a given location. The dataset you created lives in `us-central1` but your query was submitted to `us`. The location `us` and `us-central1` are not the same. Change your scheduled query to run in `us-central1`. See docs on [location](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Dataset is not provided correctly- it should be in formate `project.dataset.table`

try running below in big query

*select * from `bunny25256:dataset1`*

you should provide `bunny25256:dataset1.table`

Comment: Thanks Adi, but as I mentioned the query works OK in SQL Workspace. The project defaults to the current project if you don't specify it in a table id. I use this behavior across my projects and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

One note also you can not change the location on a saved scheduled query it will not fix the issue.   you have to create a new scheduled query and save first time to the correct location.